# Alternate Proof for $e^x \ge x+1$

Tags: calculus, inequality, proof-verification

This is just a standard problem from my high school's calculus text, but my proof seems sort of off. This is it:

Let $f(x) = e^x$. The tangent line of $f(x)$ at $x=0$ is $g(x)=x+1$. Since $f''(x_0) \gt 0$ for all $x_0 \in \mathbb R$,the tangent line $g(x) \le f(x)$ for all $x$. Q.E.D.

I didn't show all of the work, but is there something wrong here? It is pretty short. Anyways, I would like to see some alternate proofs because I tried to think of another but when my brain said, "meh", I realized that there are probably tons of ways to prove this. So just any valid proof would be cool with me. I don't care if they're crazy. It's even cooler when they're crazy. But in particular the simplest proof would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, here's yet another way of looking at it:  consider the function

$\rho(x) = e^{-x}(1 + x); \tag{1}$

we have

$\rho(0) = 1; \tag{2}$

also

$\rho'(x) = -e^{-x}(1 + x) + e^{-x} = e^{-x}(1 - (1 + x)) = -x e^{-x}. \tag{3}$

Thus

$\rho'(x) < 0 \; \; \text {for} \; \; x > 0, \tag{4}$

and

$\rho'(x) > 0 \; \; \text{for} \; \; x < 0. \tag {5}$

*Sooooo*, for $x > 0$,

$\rho(x) - 1 = \rho(x)- \rho(0) = \int_0^x \rho'(t) dt < 0, \tag{6}$

whence

$\rho(x) < 1 \tag{7}$

or, multiplying by $e^x$,

$1 + x < e^x. \tag{8}$

For $x < 0$,

$1 - \rho(x) = \rho(0) - \rho(x) = \int_x^0 \rho'(t) dt > 0, \tag{9}$

yielding again

$\rho(x) < 1, \tag{10}$

and again

$e^x < 1 + x. \tag{11}$

***QED.***

We note that that this argument uses *just a tad* of calculus, i.e. the fundamental theorem of same and the fact that $\rho(x)$ is differentiable; oh yeah, and that integrals of positive smooth functions are positive etc.  Also, we have shown that
the inequalities are strict if $x \ne 0$.

Hope this helps.  Cheers,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***

Comment: @Saudman97:  thank you for your very tasteful and judicious editing; I should have used $\int_0^x \rho'(t)dt$ etc. myself!  Well done!

Comment: Haha. Thanks! I understood what you meant, so I guess I was being a little pedantic. But I was wondering if writing $\int_x^0 \rho'(x) dx$ would change the meaning of the integral? By the way, thank you for the pretty proof!

Comment: @Saudman97:  thank *you* for the kind words!  I usually write $\int_0^x f(t)dt$ myself; it's mo' better! Regards.

Answer (score 6):

Sure, your proof is pretty short, but it is only short for someone who already did some analysis. For example, you used the following theorems (which is true, of course) in your proof:

> If $f$ is convex on $\mathbb R$, then for any tangent function $g$, we
>   know that $g(x)<f(x)$ for all $x$.

and

> If $f$ is twice differentiable on $\mathbb R$ and $f''(x)>0$ for all
>   $x$, then $f$ is convex on $\mathbb R$

You also used the definition of convex functions (implicitly) to prove your statement.

In short, I would say that your proof is short and elegant, but not simple.

---

Another way to prove your point is to simply see what the minimum value of $e^x-x-1$ is.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know how you have defined the exponential function, but you could use the fact that it has the following series expansion $$e^x = 1 + x + \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^3}{3!} +\cdots$$

Comment: This is problematic for $x<0$

Comment: You're right, good point :)

Answer (score 3):

My favourite proof is letting $f(x)=e^x-x-1$. $f(0)=0$ and it's easy to show that it has a minimum at $x=0$. 

However you do it, you are somehow going to go through derivatives or calclulus, explicitly or implicitly.

EDIT:
A completely alternative proof: Using the taylor series ($e^x = 1 + x + \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^3}{3!} +...$), it is easy to show the inequality for $x>-1$ (grouping the terms together by twos, the even ones are greater than the odd ones, the even ones being positive and the odd ones negative). For $x \leq -1$, $LHS>0$ while $RHS \leq 0$, so we are done.

Comment: You would also need to show it does not have any other minima. Conceivably f could have two minima one at zero and one somewhere else with a lower value. Or it could look like a cubic with one tail going negative. The covexity in 5xum solution is important.

Comment: Well it's pretty trivial :D (I meant global minimum in the post)

Answer (score 3):

When $x>=0$, $e^x>=1+x$.

When $x <-1$, $\;1+x < 0$, so $e^x>=1+x$

When $ -1\leq x \lt 0$, then lets take $y = -x$, so,

$$e^x=e^{-y}=(1-y)+y^2(1/2!-y/3!+\cdots>=(1-y)+y^2((1/2!-1/3!)+y^2(1/4!-1/5!)+\cdots)\geq (1-y)\geq(1+x)$$

[Remember, $(1/n!-1/(n+1)!>0$]

Comment: "When $x\ge 0$, $e^x\ge 1+x$"- What exactly is the justification for this? Otherwise this is pretty cool!

Comment: @Saudman97 - Agreed.  I should have completed $x >= 0$ case.

Comment: Do try to write using LaTeX on Math SE. You can find a reference at http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference.